# MemoryError on dask.linalg.solve(A, b) for solving Ax = b

Tags: python, dask

I want to solve an equation Ax=b with a **big, symmetric, dense matrix A** (>100GB). I am trying Dask because it is supposed to be a nice high level API for python to work with big data.

This is my code:

```
n = 100000 # makes 75GB array
chunk_size = 5000
A = da.random.random(size=(n, n), chunks=(chunk_size, chunk_size))
b = np.random.random(n)
x = da.linalg.solve(A, b)
res = x.compute()
```

Unfortunately I get the following error, apparently because A is too big. Is there any smart mechanism in Dask that prevents a MemoryError (e.g. iteratively solving the problem)?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_solver.py", line 27, in <module>
x = da.linalg.solve(A, b)
File "..\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\array\linalg.py", line 916, in solve
File "..\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\array\linalg.py", line 755, in lu
MemoryError
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem isn't that the array is too big, but that your chunks are too small: the array is made up of 1,000,000 pieces, and the solve graph contains exponentially more tasks.

For example, if you have a chunk size of 5000x5000 (190Mbyte per chunk), you get

```
In [5]: n = 100000 # makes 75GB array
   ...: chunk_size = 5000
   ...: A = da.random.random(size=(n, n), chunks=(chunk_size, chunk_size))
   ...: b = np.random.random(n)
   ...: x = da.linalg.solve(A, b)
In [7]: len(x.dask)
6541
```

6541 tasks in the graph. If the chunk size is 1000x1000, you get 427401 tasks.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html